# Яндекс карты отзывы редактировать виджет

Tags: html, css, яндекс-карты, виджет

Есть готовый виджет от яндекс карт
`

```html
<div style="width:750px;height:500px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;margin-left:55px;">
    <iframe style="width:100%;height:100%; border:1px solid #e6e6e6;border-radius:8px;box-sizing:border-box" src="https://yandex.ru/maps-reviews-widget/***********?comments">
    </iframe>
    <a href="https://yandex.ru/maps/org/family_cars/***********/" target="_blank" style="box-sizing:border-box;text-decoration:none;color:#b3b3b3;font-size:10px;font-family:YS Text,sans-serif;padding:0 20px;position:absolute;bottom:8px;width:100%;text-align:center;left:0;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;display:block;max-height:14px;white-space:nowrap;padding:0 16px;box-sizing:border-box">********* на карте Москвы — Яндекс Карты
    </a>
</div>
```

`
как можно изменить стиль в CSS подгружаемых отзывов?
*(к примеру)*

```
.badge__link-to-map {
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите этот класс badge__link-to-map внутри нужного тега, например:

```
`<div class="badge__link-to-map"...>`
```

Или добавьте Ваши стили:
`background: #000000; color: #fff;` в style виджета:

```
`style="background: #000000; color: #fff;..."`
```

Также, полагаю, при формировании этого виджета на Яндекс.Картах существует пользовательский интерфейс, где можно просто выбрать цвет фона и текста.